# Adding email and phone field to Woocommerce analytics order report

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I add the field `email` and `phone` to the Woocommerce reports?

The report I want to display the email can be seen if you go to Analytics > Orders. There you can see the order ID, billing name etc. but not `email` and `phone` fields.

I have tried to look at this links with no luck:

- https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-admin/#/data?id=sqlquery-class
- https://developer.woocommerce.com/2021/02/04/adding-columns-to-analytics-reports-and-csv-downloads/

Comment: Have you already looked inside the code for any hooks/filters? Would be my first place to search.